# How to get the rank of one numpy array based on intervals from another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays:

```py
arr = np.array([.10,.80,.10,.20,.60,.50,.80,1.00])
intervals = [.20,.35,.60,1.00]
```

Required ranks:

```
[1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reshape into a long format and compare each element to the intervals.  The argmax() will return the values you are looking for.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([10,80,10,20,60,50,80,100])
intervals = np.array([20,35,60,100]) # this is always increasing

(arr.reshape(-1,1) < intervals).argmax(axis=1)+1
```

Output

```
array([1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.digitize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) for this:

```
binned = np.digitize(arr, intervals) + 1
ans_dict = dict(zip(arr, binned))
```

Output:

```
>>> ans_dict
{
    0.1: 1,
    0.8: 4,
    0.2: 2,
    0.6: 4,
    0.5: 3,
    1.0: 5,
}
```

Comment: It was great but did not work for the floats, How to deal with the floats, I have edited the question.

Comment: @usermay14 try now.